# Q: Assembly: A2071 error. Wont compile, but error location doesn't mean anything?

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm using Visual Studio to write an assembly program using C++. I'm getting two errors:

1. A2071, initializer magnitude too large for specified size. It states this in my assembly file at Line 1, but that's where I have the processor (.586) at. Even if I move it to line 2, it says the issue is at line 1 (even when line 1 is empty?
2. I have an A2044 code. Invalid character in file. However, I don't believe anything non-standard is in the code.

I went to a professor at my university and he couldn't figure it out either.

```
.586 
.MODEL FLAT, C ;Use flat memory model and C calling conventions 
.STACK ;Define a stack segment of 1KB 
.DATA
string  DB   "ATest This String?.,/[}", '$'
strSize DD  23
.CODE
strToLower  PROC
        LEA     EAX, string
        PUSH    EAX
        CALL    toLower2    ; write toLower2
        POP EAX
        LEA EAX, string     ; return char* to C++
        RET
strToLower  ENDP

;---------------------------------------------
;Procedure: Convert to LowerCase
;Input: Address in EBX
;       unsigned in AL for each letter
;Output: EAX will contain new string
;---------------------------------------------

toLower2    PROC    ;65-90 is upper, 97-122 is lower (XOR 32?)
            LEA EBX, string
            MOV ECX, strSize
            PUSH AX     ; PUSH AL before manipulating it
loop1:      MOV AL, [EBX]   ; Put char into AL to manipulate
            XOR BL, BL          ;?????????????
            MOV BL, AL          ;Set condition here???
            SUB BL, 65          ;Capital A (65)
            CMP BL, 25          ;if(i > 64 && < 90) i += 32;
            JA  NoCap           ;
            ADD AL, 32          ;Adds 32 to ASCII value, making lower 
NoCap:      MOV [EBX], AL
            INC EBX
            LOOP loop1
            POP AX      ;Replace/POP AL
            LEA EAX, string
toLower2    ENDP
            END
```

My C++ looks like this:

```
extern "C" { char* strToLower(); }

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* pChar = strToLower();     // prints  atest this string?.,/[}$
    cout << pChar << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `extern "C" { char* strToLower(); }` Can someone enlighten me about that?

Comment: @Treycos That's how you declare an ordinary C function so that C++ can call it.

Comment: @Treycos In this case, it just tells it not to do C++ name mangling.

Comment: String size 23 doesn't add an extra byte for the null terminator.

Comment: Please specify the exact command you're using to assemble the assembly code. And also which version of MASM you're using.

Comment: is using BL for data while using EBX as index a good idea ?